# Do not saute baby spinach

Tags: sauteing, greens

I read in a cooking magazine that baby spinach should only be eaten raw because ooking it results in slimy texture. Regular spinach can be sauteed/wilted without any issues.

Do many culinary sites state the same? I am looking at making spanakopita as well as Tuscan chicken and some others.

Answer (score 10):

I've sauteed baby spinach many times and I've never had it become slimy. I've never seen a cookbook or article that stated that either.